# c# updating only the values with inputs on the view with razor page with entity framework CORE

Tags: entity-framework-core, razor-pages

I'm using razor pages and EF CORE and have retrieved values from the database and put them in the view like so

```
<input asp-for="theModel.theValue1" class="form-control" />
```

using `BindProperty`

```
[BindProperty]
public theModel theModel { get; set; }
```

So far, so by-the-documentation.   I have another value in the model called `theValue2` which is to remain unchanged when this view is submitted.   If I save the view using

```
_context.Attach(theModel).State = EntityState.Modified;
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

then `theModel.theValue2` is null as I don't have a corresponding input on the view itself which is as you'd expect with statelessness.

Is the only way to persist values between edits to put a hidden input on the view for each property in the model like so

```
<input type="hidden" asp-for="theModel.theValue2" />
```

or is there a more elegant way of saying either "only update `theModel.theValue1`" or "don't update `theModel.theValue2`"?

Answer (score 1):

This is the only way to transfer your data between postbacks but it is not safe. It is very easy for the visitor of you web application to change the value of a hidden input.

I usually read the data from database again when the user posts data and I set the new values for the entity that I retrieved from database (for your case you will set the value for theModel property) and save the modified entity back to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Not on my pc now, but I'm pretty sure you could so something like

```
_context.Entry(theModel).Property(t => t.theValue2).IsModified = false;
```

Before calling the save.